# How can I hide a specific column form a dataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I hide a specific Column in `DataGridview` along with its header 
while being able to use its value ? ( just doesn't get shown ) . 
The following code doesn't work.

```
 gridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[11].Visible = false;
```

Comment: you can use `datakeynames`, see my answer below :)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try this:

```
gridview.Columns["ColumnName"].Visible = false;
```

[Hide Columns in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c24a0d7.aspx)

Comment: Is there a way to hide the columns when my code is like this:                         mainContenttabControl.TabPages[i].Controls.Add(new DataGridView()
                        {
                            Name = "dataGridView_" + tabTitle,
                            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                            DataSource = selectedSensors,
                            AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
                        });
?

Comment: The First and second one.

Comment: Nah, the problem is that i cant acces the .Columns prop. in my specific code.

Comment: No, the question is if it is possible to addgridview.Columns["ColumnName"].Visible = false; to my code.

Comment: If you have some specific case, consider to create a separate question. Then you can host your source code better.

Answer (score 6):

This is 100% correct solution....
`this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;`

Answer (score 0):

Add the column name/s to the `DataKeyNames` of the grid view...

```
<asp:gridview id="GridView1" runat="server" datakeynames="ColumnName" onselectedindexchange="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:gridview>
```

you can then access the datakeys in the code behind...

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textbox.Text = GridView1.DataKeys[GridView1.SelectedIndex].Values["ColumnName"].ToString();
}
```

You can add more `DataKeyNames` by separating with a comma. Then you don't need to add the column to the `GridView` at all if you don't want to.

Comment: Thanks but i needed a windform solution :)

Comment: apologies, I did not spot that! perhaps there is a similar solution for winforms...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide gridview column, you should have a **condition**..

```
if(userlevel != 'Administrator')
{
      GridView.Columns["ColumnName"].Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call this how ever you see fit.  The data is still available to the app whether visible or not.

```
private void showHideGridColumns(bool show)
{
    List<String> lstColNames = new List<string>();
    lstColNames.Add("Column1");
    lstColNames.Add("Column2");
    lstColNames.Add("Column3");
    lstColNames.Add("Column4");
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn Col in DataGridView1.Columns)
    {
        if (!lstColNames.Contains(Col.Name.ToString()))
        {
            Col.Visible = show;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
GridView.Columns[index of Column].Visible = false;
```

Comment: Please, edit your question to add an explanation. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).