# C# Datagridview don't show primary key

Tags: c#, sql, gridview, primary-key

Currently I'm setting up a gridview, this is my code:

```
//tabel
        conn.Open();
        sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT Totaal,Nr,Datum,Beginstand,Eindstand,van,Naar,Bezoekadres,Geredenroute,Karakterrit,Toelichting,KilometersZakelijk,KilometersPrive from ars.Kmstand", conn);
        dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        metroGrid1.DataSource = dt;
```

I don't want to show the primary key (Totaal) but when I don't use it in the query the table won't update.

How can I let the primary key into the query but don't show it?

Comment: Just hide the column `metroGrid1.Columns[0].Visible = false`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I hide a specific column form a dataGridView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090093/how-can-i-hide-a-specific-column-form-a-datagridview)

Comment: Thankyou I already tried that but on the wrong one I did dt.Columns[0].Visible = false;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just hide it in the `DataGridView`. Either by

```
metroGrid1.Columns[indexOfPrimaryKey].Visible = false;
```

or by checking the names of the columns and hiding those you do not want.